# Create n matrices input by user

Tags: java

I'm having a pratice to create a n matrices with the same size. And I want to put it in a loop. Each matrix have a name.

So I decided to use OOP to implement these matrices:

In class matrix:

```
public class Matrix
{
  static double mat[][] = null;

  public matrix(int size)
  {

    mat = new double[size][size];
   for (int i = 0; i< size; i++)
     {
       for(int j = 0 ; j< size;j++)
          {
                 mat[i][j] = 0;
          }
     }
   }
   }
```

I have sucessfully create a loop but now the problem is I can't control the matrix. Like I want to change values in each matrix.

In main class:

```
 for(int  i = 0 ; i<n ;i++)
 {
     Matrix m = new Matrix(4);
     m.print(plan);
     System.out.println( );
 }
```

My expectation is:
 input: n = 4
 output: 4 matrices

Comment: I don't understand your question, you want to know how to create the matrice with a `n` size ? Simply `Matrix m = new Matrix(n)`.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I edited the post

Comment: Start by removing the static keyword. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html. Then read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

Comment: in main class, I want to make a loop like "for(int i =0;i<n;i++)". And with each " i " counted, we created a matrix

Comment: You're on the right track. Just do it. What prevents you from doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your class, here's some pseudo-code to help you:

```
-- Read user desired size
-- create a list of Matrix objects (List<Matrix> matrixList = new ArrayList<>();)
-- loop over the user input : for(int cur =0; cur<desiredNumberOfMatrices; cur++)
-- in each loop initiate a new matrix and add it to the list: 

Matrix mat = new Matrix(size);
matrixList.add(mat);

-- do whatever you want next
```

I don't see why you might be stuck.